# Trying to connect to sqlite db using schemacrawler using OSX - why is it asking for a user?

Tags: macos, sqlite, jdbc, schemacrawler

See bottom for conclusion:

I'm trying to use schemacrawler to diagram a sqlite database.  My setup:

- OSX 10.8
- SchemaCrawler 10.5 downloaded from [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/schemacrawler/files/SchemaCrawler%20-%20SQLite/10.5/)
- Java version 1.7.0_45 downloaded from Oracle
- sqlite version: 3.7.12 2012-04-03 19:43:07 86b8481be7e76cccc92d14ce762d21bfb69504af

I'm in the directory where I installed schemacrawler, and using this command line:

```
stebro$ java -classpath lib/*:. schemacrawler.tools.sqlite.Main /Library/Application\ Support/MyApp/Data/MyApp.db -command="select count(*) from myTable" -infolevel=maximum
SchemaCrawler 10.5
Copyright (c) 2000-2013, Sualeh Fatehi.

SchemaCrawler is a database schema discovery and comprehension tool. 
You can search for database schema objects using regular expressions, 
and output the schema and data in a readable text format. You can find 
potential schema design issues with lint. The output serves for 
database documentation is designed to be diff-ed against other database 
schemas. SchemaCrawler also generates schema diagrams.
password: 
java.sql.SQLException: Could not connect to database, for user null
    at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getConnection(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:93)
    at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getConnection(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:70)
    at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.execute(SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.java:173)
    at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerMain.main(SchemaCrawlerMain.java:93)
    at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerMain.main(SchemaCrawlerMain.java:52)
    at schemacrawler.tools.sqlite.Main.main(Main.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Insufficient parameters for database connection URL: missing [database]
    at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.DatabaseConfigConnectionOptions.getConnectionUrl(DatabaseConfigConnectionOptions.java:73)
    at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getConnection(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:89)
    ... 5 more
```

If I specify -password, I get the same error, and specifying various values for -user does the same.  Sqlite requires no user/password - why is the jdbc or schemacrawler asking me for one?

Addendum:

Here is a specific series of commands that creates a simple database then attempts to diagram it with schemacrawler:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 MyApp.db
sqlite3 MyApp.db
SQLite version 3.7.12 2012-04-03 19:43:07
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table smbtest(col1 integer, col2 integer);
create table smbtest(col1 integer, col2 integer);
sqlite> ^D 
bash-3.2$ ~/bin/sunjava -classpath lib/*:. schemacrawler.tools.sqlite.Main -database=MyApp.db -infolevel=maximum -command=graph -outputformat=pdf -outputfile=myapp.pdf
SchemaCrawler 10.5
Copyright (c) 2000-2013, Sualeh Fatehi.

SchemaCrawler is a database schema discovery and comprehension tool. 
You can search for database schema objects using regular expressions, 
and output the schema and data in a readable text format. You can find 
potential schema design issues with lint. The output serves for 
database documentation is designed to be diff-ed against other database 
schemas. SchemaCrawler also generates schema diagrams.
password: 

Graphviz was not available to create the requested graph. Please reinstall 
Graphviz, and make it available on the system PATH. Meanwhile, a .dot text file 
has been created instead. This .dot file can be opened in any Graphviz file 
viewer.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dot": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
at schemacrawler.tools.integration.graph.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:124)
at schemacrawler.tools.integration.graph.GraphGenerator.generateDiagram(GraphGenerator.java:87)
at schemacrawler.tools.integration.graph.GraphExecutable.executeOn(GraphExecutable.java:123)
at schemacrawler.tools.executable.SchemaCrawlerExecutable.executeOn(SchemaCrawlerExecutable.java:87)
at schemacrawler.tools.executable.BaseExecutable.execute(BaseExecutable.java:77)
at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.execute(SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.java:176)
at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerMain.main(SchemaCrawlerMain.java:93)
at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerMain.main(SchemaCrawlerMain.java:52)
at schemacrawler.tools.sqlite.Main.main(Main.java:43)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
... 9 more
```

Final conclusion:
The problem lay in the fact that the path to my db had a space in it; no combination of backslashing, double or single quotes, or both resolved the issue.  Running the command from the same directory as my db file did the trick.  The space issue may be due to my not understanding the right escape sequences to use in bash - I may have to double-escape the spaces if schemacrawler is spawning other processes using my name as part of the command line.

However, the app did continue to ask for my password, but just pressing enter allowed it to continue successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve,

You need to specify the database like this:

```
"-database=/Library/Application Support/MyApp/Data/MyApp.db"
```

Notice the double-quotes to allow for the space in the path to the database file, and the -database command-line switch. I also removed the back-slash, since the whole switch in enclosed in double-quotes.

For help on the command-line, simply run:

```
java -classpath lib/*:. schemacrawler.tools.sqlite.Main
```

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I tried your solution; unfortunately it also doesn't work.  Here's the command I used:

~/bin/sunjava -classpath lib/*:. schemacrawler.tools.sqlite.Main -database="/Library/Application Support/MyApp/Data/MyApp.db" -infolevel=maximum -command=graph -outputformat=pdf -outputfile=carb.pdf

(sunjava points to the Oracle java distribution as opposed to the 1.6 java version Apple provides).

I still get prompted for a password, and I still get errors regardless of the answer I supply.

Comment: See my changes to my submission above for a repeatable example on any system

Comment: Steve, you will need to install GraphViz, and have it on your path, Also, you should move this discussion to the SchemaCrawler forums - https://sourceforge.net/p/schemacrawler/discussion/495991/

Answer (score 1):

**Generating DB Schema ER Diagram using SchemaCrawler We can visualize our DB schema using SchemaCrawler Download the latest package from here:** 
https://github.com/sualeh/SchemaCrawler/releases/

Copy _schemacrawler folder and rename it to schemacrawler to another location and add the directory path of the same to PATH Use GraphViz to create schema diagram http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/diagramming.html

Cd into schemacrawler directory and run ./schemacrawler.sh(on mac and ubuntu env) with option as mentioned below.

You can run sample command to get the schema diagram in the form of png image for postgre db:

```
./schemacrawler.sh -command graph -outputformat png -outputfile=dh_er.png -loglevel=CONFIG -server=postgresql -host=localhost -port=5432 -database=testdb -user=testuser -password=testpass -infolevel=standard
```

To include/exclude some tables you need to define configuration 
in schemacrawler.config.properties as example:

```
schemacrawler.table.pattern.include=.*askbot_activityauditstatus |.*askbot_anonymousanswer|.*askbot_anonymousquestion |.*askbot_askwidget|.*askbot_badgedata|.*askbot_bulktagsubscription |.*askbot_bulktagsubscription_groups|.*askbot_bulktagsubscription_tags
```

schemacrawler.table.pattern.exclude is the key. value of the same is the JAVA regex pattern

Note: If you are facing "SERVICE: Cannot run program "dot": error=2, No such file or directory" issue...

```
 Please install below(for mac only):
 Install the app : brew install graphviz
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are specifying `-classpath` correctly.  I think you need a wrapper shell script around that command to expand each `.jar` in `lib` so that it's separated with `:` characters:

```
#!/bin/sh

classpath="."

for j in lib/*.jar
do
    classpath=$classpath:$j
done

java -classpath $classpath schemacrawler.tools.sqlite.Main /Library/Application\ Support/MyApp/Data/MyApp.db -command="select count(*) from myTable" -infolevel=maximum
```

Just a stab-in-the-dark but that's the way I've always done it.  Obviously this is more complicated if non-`jar` classpaths have to be included as well...

Comment: I tried your solution; unfortunately, it doesn't work; I still get it prompting me for a password, and ultimately getting errors about null users or invalid users (if I specify one).