# Not able to connect to MSSQL using Schemacrawler

Tags: java, sql-server, schemacrawler

I have installed Java 8 and I have the SchemaCrawler folder on E: on my machine. I run SQL Server 2012.

The cmd command used is below

```
sc.cmd -c graph -host=10.52.136.168  -user=sa -database=MyDBName schemacrawler.Main -infolevel=detailed -schemas=dbo -tabletypes=TABLE -outputformat=pdf -outputfile=database-diagram.pdf %*
```

I have checked the suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659846/trying-to-connect-to-sqlite-db-using-schemacrawler-using-osx-why-is-it-asking)
but no luck . I still get the below error

```
schemacrawler.schemacrawler.SchemaCrawlerSQLException: Could not connect to jdbc
:hsqldb:hsql://10.52.136.168:9001/DeliveryIntelligence;readonly=true;hsqldb.lock
_file=false, with properties {user=sa}
        at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getConnecti
on(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:122)
        at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getConnecti
on(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:70)
        at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.execute(Sche
maCrawlerCommandLine.java:176)
        at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerMain.main(SchemaCrawlerM
ain.java:78)
        at schemacrawler.tools.hsqldb.Main.main(Main.java:43)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException:
Connection refused: connect
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getConnecti
on(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:115)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refus
ed: connect
        at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.openConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.initConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.HsqlSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using SchemaCrawler for HyperSQL. Please download and use [SchemaCrawler for SQL Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/schemacrawler/files/SchemaCrawler%20-%20Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/) instead.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler

Comment: Sorry.. My bad there was a misleading download latest version link there. Will try with the actual file

Comment: Now, although it generates a PDF, the pdf is empty. Am I missing any parameter in the cmd command?

Comment: First try without the -schemas:

sc.cmd -c graph -host=10.52.136.168 -user=sa -database=MyDBName schemacrawler.Main -infolevel=standard -outputformat=pdf -outputfile=database-diagram.pdf

then, use something like 

-schemas=MyDBName.dbo

Comment: Voila! I used -schemas=MyDBName.dbo and it worked! It is much more readable than the default MSSQL diagram! Thanks!

Comment: Also, an additional change made was to append path variable as mentioned at http://www.graphviz.org/content/failed-run-dot for Graphviz